# Isn't Hadoop more of a grid than a cluster?

Tags: hadoop, grid, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, bigdata

I've heard the term "Hadoop cluster", but it seems to be contrary to what my understanding of a "grid" and a "cluster" are.

My *understanding* is that a **grid** is a distributed system consisting of 2+ computers (nodes) that are all sharing computing resources with each other to *solve the same problem*. Ergo, if you were trying to do some kind of heavy duty scientific computing, number-crunching, you would create a grid of machines to all collaborate over the same problem.

My *understanding* of a **cluster** is that it is a distributed system consisting of 2+ computers that are all *working independently to solve different, smaller problems*. Hence  you typically place a cluster behind a load balancer and let each node solve a small problem when the load balancer assigns it one.

So, if my understanding is correct, then you use grids to solve small numbers of gigantic (computationally heavy) jobs, and clusters to solve high numbers of small (computationally light) jobs.

So first, if my understanding of grids and clusters is incorrect, please begin by correcting me!

Assuming I'm more or less correct, then why do we have Hadoop *clusters*? If the purpose of Hadoop is take a Big Data problem (some computationally-heavy problem) and use lots of commodity hardware to create lots of nodes capable of collaborating with the others to solve the same problem, isn't that a *grid*?

Is it more correct to say that we have Hadoop *grids*? Why or why not? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wikipedia has some [examples of grid computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_computing) which might clear up the distinction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding is partially correct. I'd like to add a few things that would probably clear some air. It is correct that Hadoop is used to solve BigData problems. But it does so by converting  1 big task into a no. of smaller tasks and each of these smaller tasks is solved on different machines(nodes) in isolation. The nodes do not communicate with each other and they do not share any resource either. Each machine has its own memory, CPU and disk which is used during the processing and has nothing to do with other machines' resources.

So, if you analyze it microscopically you'll find that while you are trying to solve "1" big problem, you eventually end up processing "n" smaller isolated problems as opposite to grid computing wherein all the nodes try to solve the same problem.

Another important aspect is that in a Grid your interaction is with the system as a whole and not with any node(s) in particular which is not the case when you submit a job to hadoop cluster for processing. You submit your job to the "master" node and don't have to worry about the "slaves" or the task distribution etc. Once your job has been submitted to the master node it automatically gets split into "n" smaller jobs and the master takes care of starting the process on "n" different systems automatically.

Hadoop actually represents the "Distributed Computing" paradigm and you could think of it as a subset of Grid Computing.

One more thing. You have specified about "load balancing" in your question. You could actually visualize it while playing with hadoop. When you start processing a job on a hadoop cluster all "n" smaller jobs('coz of task splitting as specified earlier) get processed in a balanced fashion. Balanced here means that all the slave nodes get equal(approximately if not perfectly) amount of data to process on equal(ideally) amount of resources.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @Tariq (+1) - awesome answer, however it left me confused in one respect! Your 3rd paragraph is a *little* confusing: are you saying that Hadoop *is like* a grid in the sense that you submit 1 job to a master, and only interact with that master? Or are you saying that Hadoop *is not like* a grid, and that you have to decompose a job into smaller units, and submit each unit to a slave? Thanks for the clarification here!

Comment: You'r welcome TM and sorry for the confusion. By that I mean that in a Grid you submit the job to the system as a whole and not with any specific node(s). On the other hand in a Distributed Computing environment you just keep on firing request to specific node(s) which is he master node in case of Hadoop. HTH

Comment: Thanks again @Tariq, but still not sure: which one of these two models does Hadoop fit into?!?

Comment: I would say Distributed Computing :)